# Microsoft Graph - Get events error

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I am trying to get meetings in a given user time range using the following request:

```
"/users/xxx//events?$filter=createdDateTime ge 2018-07-01T00:00:00Z  or lastModifiedDateTime  ge 2018-07-01T00:00:00Z&$top=50"
```

In response, I get user meetings but, unlike usual, without iCalUId as you can check in the following payload:

```
{
"@odata.etag": "",
"id": "",
"createdDateTime": "",
"lastModifiedDateTime": "",
"changeKey": "",
"categories": Array[0][],
"originalStartTimeZone": "GMT Standard Time",
"originalEndTimeZone": "GMT Standard Time",
"reminderMinutesBeforeStart": 15,
"isReminderOn": true,
"hasAttachments": false,
"subject": "JM:Reunião",
"bodyPreview": "",
"importance": "normal",
"sensitivity": "normal",
"isAllDay": false,
"isCancelled": false,
"isOrganizer": true,
"responseRequested": true,
"seriesMasterId": null,
"showAs": "busy",
"type": "singleInstance",
"webLink": "",
"onlineMeetingUrl": null,
"recurrence": null,
"responseStatus": {
},
"body": {},
"start": {},
"end": {},
"location": {},
"locations": Array[1][],
"attendees": Array[1][],
"organizer": {}
},
```

Only some users that we have in office 365 do not get this key. What is wrong? Any idea?

Comment: Let me know if this link helps. https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/findmeetingtimes_example

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been confirmed as a bug with the Graph schema which will fixed in future release. I will provide updates once the latest graph schema is available with the fix.